# Trouble with gradient border-bottom ie10 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, gradient

Why this code works properly in IE10?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<STYLE type="text/css">

ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
sectionHeader{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:dashed 1px #99f;
    color:#99f;
    position:relative;
}

sectionHeader:after{
     content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 100%;
        color: red;
        left: 0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
</STYLE>

<META name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.16798"></HEAD>
<BODY> 
<DIV class="sectionHeader">
<UL>
  <LI>Link 1</LI>
  <LI>Link 2</LI>
  <LI>Link 3</LI></UL></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

But when i define SectionHeader in Main.CSS in my asp.net application it doesn't work properly. Browser displays only border without gradient.
Sorry for terrible English.

Comment: I assume that CSS **does** include the `.` dot to denote a class? Please provide a JSFiddle.

Comment: what he said. I'd go further to ask if that's really a 2px tall gradient? If so, why not just use border-top and border-bottom of the :after element and do away with the gradient entirely?

Comment: here you are
http://jsfiddle.net/t8wT4/